# How to use the PrimeVue i18n integration?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, primevue

I created a Vue 3 app using the CLI and added PrimeVue to my project. Based on the [docs](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/locale) I want to setup the locales.

Inside the *main.ts* file I tried to setup a sample with multiple languages

```
  .use(PrimeVue, {
    locale: {
      en: {
        message: "Message",
      },
      ja: {
        message: "メッセージ",
      },
      de: {
        message: "Nachricht",
      },
    },
  })
```

and this is a sample component trying to work with `message` based on the selected locale

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <button @click="setCurrentLocaleToJapanese">Change to japanese</button>
  </div>  
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { usePrimeVue } from "primevue/config";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const primevue = usePrimeVue();

    const message = ref(primevue.config.currentLocale.message); // reactive, fallback locale?

    function setCurrentLocaleToJapanese() {
      primevue.config.currentLocale = "ja";
    }

    return { message };
  },
});
</script>
```

My whole code is pseudo code because I don't know the correct syntax yet. I'm struggling with multiple problems:

- How to configure a fallback locale?
- Is there something similiar to vue-i18n to access the correct translation for `message` eg `{{ $t('message') }}`? This `const message = ref(primevue.config.currentLocale.message);` is wrong.
- How to change the current selected locale globally?

Comment: You question is a bit broad and maybe a bit specific. You could try to post this question in their Github repository: https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues

Comment: hm yeah tried it here but got no answer yet :/ https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=110&t=70571&p=197104#p197104

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/locale) that you linked, there is no nesting per locale in the `.use(PrimeVue, {})`.

So you have to declare your defaults as:

```js
.use(PrimeVue, {
    locale: {
        emptyFilterMessage: 'There is no records',
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to switch locale you have to override every locale as stated in the documentation:

```
const primevue = usePrimeVue();
primevue.config.locale.emptyFilterMessage = 'I wish there were some records';
```

> How to configure a fallback locale?

There does not seem to have any mechanism to have a fallback locale. But you can simulate this, in fact if you use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you can have something like:

```js
primevue.config.locale = Object.assign(
  {},
  en, // fallback, an object like { emptyFilterMessage: 'Empty', emptyMessage: 'empty...' }
  de, // locale, an object like { emptyFilterMessage: 'Leer' }
);
```

Note: The `en` and `de` could results from `import`s.

> Is there something similiar to vue-i18n to access the correct translation ?

You can use `primevue.config.locale.<key>` directly in your template, such as:

```js
<template>
  <p>{{ primevue.config.locale.emptyFilterMessage }}</p>
</template>
```

> How to change the current selected locale globally ?

I would advise you to use a [store](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html) (usually Vuex) in order to achieve this.

The idea being that when you switch to another locale, the store will be responsible to update `primevue.config.locale`, so your whole app will update its messages.

Comment: So I would have to create a .ts file for each locale, import them, load them into the store and override each `primevue.config.locale.<key>` with the values from the import in a loop? Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: I advise you to create a `.ts` file for each locale. You do not need a loop to override the values (as shown with `Object.assign`). From the documentation this seems to be the way of doing that....

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/locale ... still a valid answer in 2022

Comment: @ESP32 No, it's [primefaces.org/primevue/locale](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/locale) now... ;)